# Writing to a file using fputs

Tags: c, linux

I have the following simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        char buffer[20] = "abc";
        FILE *pFile;

        pFile = fopen("myfile1.txt", "r+");
        fputs("def", pFile);
        fgets(buffer, 20, pFile);
        printf("buffer content: %s\n", buffer);

        fclose(pFile);
        return 0;
}
```

the output is: `buffer content: abc`, not `def` as it has just been written to the file. Could someone please explain?

Comment: Do you have myfile1.txt already created?

Comment: Yes, but is it importent?

Comment: That r+ won't create a file if it doesn't exist

Comment: So as i said the file exists.

Comment: you can't write in a file open as read only... (r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to read randomly, you first have to tell the file reading routines, where you want to start.

Use `fseek`to do this.

e.g.: `fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_SET)` before you try to get something with `fgets`.

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen):

> In update mode ('+'), both input and output may be performed, but output cannot be followed by input without an intervening call to fflush, fseek, fsetpos or rewind, and input cannot be followed by output without an intervening call to fseek, fsetpos or rewind, unless the input operation encountered end of file.

You're not doing any of those things between writing and reading.

Comment: Ok, so `fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_SET)` before `fgets` works, but `fflush` doesn't. Why?

Comment: You need to set the position to start (in your example), otherwise after you put the string into the file, the file position is at the end of the file. There is nothing left to read, so you read nothing. The buffer stays as it was.

Comment: @Daros The file offset needs to be to a location in the file where there is something to be read. Probably isn't after just flushing unless you're writing into the middle of the file.

Comment: So what's the purpose of `fflush` on a file like `fflush(pFile)`?

Comment: Could anyone answer my last question please?

Comment: @Daros: You could accept my answer as it successfully answered your main question ;-)

Comment: @Daros: Man pages give good descriptions for standard c functions. You find them on your local system or in the web: https://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush